# NoMethodError: undefined method `prompts' for nil:NilClass

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

After I configured MCF encountered the following error when I execute the following command:

```
sunmatoMacBook-Pro-2:~ sunshiguo$ cf target
target: http://api.telemetry.cloudfoundry.me
sunmatoMacBook-Pro-2:~ sunshiguo$ cf register
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/interactive.rb:569: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Email> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/interactive.rb:571: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777


Email> 

Email> 

Email> 

Email> ssg188550@gmail.com

Password> ******

Confirm Password> ******

Your password strength is: unknown
Creating user... FAILED
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_user' for nil:NilClass
For more information, see ~/.cf/crash
sunmatoMacBook-Pro-2:~ sunshiguo$ cf login
target: http://api.telemetry.cloudfoundry.me

NoMethodError: undefined method `prompts' for nil:NilClass
For more information, see ~/.cf/crash
```

I ask these errors are caused by what? How
To solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try vmc command.it works to me.